# How to activate flash cards

Tags: customization

I have been blogging at wordpress for the past 6 months and very recently i came to know about the flash cards. Can anyone let me know as to how to activate flash cards in wordpress. I tried going to the "extras" option but then i can't see anything regarding flash cards over there.

Comment: No idea what feature you refer to (don't think it is something native), please elaborate? Also self-hosted WordPress or wordpress.com blog?

Comment: In wordpress.com blog

Comment: This should be asked on http://en.support.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about the hovercards for gravatar users? It's available on WP.com, not for self-install sites. However, there's a fairly easy hack to get it working anywhere.

See this article:
http://ottopress.com/2010/gravatar-hovercards/

Comment: Question is about wordpress.com Still not sure what feature it is about since @Chandru1 didn't explain that clearly.